# How to convert binary value to decimal in hive/impala

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, impala

I want to convert a value - 00000000000100100000000000000111 which is in string to equivalent decimal value - 1179655 in Hive/Impala.Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below:

```sql
SELECT conv('100100000000000000111', 2, 10)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: can you please let me know how to convert 1179655 to 00000000000100100000000000000111 in Hive/impala?

Comment: would you try `conv(1179655, 10, 2)` ?